# How to append dynamically generated recursive sections of DOM elements to its parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, recursion, dom

I am trying to create a dynamic form based on the json data

```
const input_def =     {
           "model_class":"Conditional",
           "name":"SelPlotting",
           "type":"conditional",
           "cases":[
              {
                 "model_class":"ConditionalWhen",
                 "value":"HeatMap",
                 "inputs":[
                    {
                       "model_class":"DataToolParameter",
                       "name":"InFile",
                       "argument":"--InFile",
                       "type":"data",
                       "label":"Input file",
                       "help":"Tabular data file",
                       "refresh_on_change":true,
                       "optional":false,
                       "hidden":false,
                       "is_dynamic":false,
                       "value":"None",
                       "extensions":[
                          "tabular"
                       ],
                       "edam":{
                          "edam_formats":[
                             "format_3475"
                          ],
                          "edam_data":[
                             "data_0006"
                          ]
                       },
                       "multiple":false,
                       "options":{
                          "hda":[
                             
                          ],
                          "hdca":[
                             
                          ]
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "model_class":"TextToolParameter",
                       "name":"IndexColumn",
                       "argument":"--IndexColumn",
                       "type":"text",
                       "label":"Index Column",
                       "help":"Column name that contains index as row/sample names ",
                       "refresh_on_change":false,
                       "optional":false,
                       "hidden":false,
                       "is_dynamic":false,
                       "value":"Index",
                       "area":false,
                       "datalist":[
                          
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "model_class":"TextToolParameter",
                       "name":"x_label",
                       "argument":"--x_label",
                       "type":"text",
                       "label":"Label for x-axis",
                       "help":"A label that describes x axis",
                       "refresh_on_change":false,
                       "optional":false,
                       "hidden":false,
                       "is_dynamic":false,
                       "value":"x-axis",
                       "area":false,
                       "datalist":[
                          
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "model_class":"TextToolParameter",
                       "name":"y_label",
                       "argument":"--y_label",
                       "type":"text",
                       "label":"Label for y-axis",
                       "help":"A label that describes y axis",
                       "refresh_on_change":false,
                       "optional":false,
                       "hidden":false,
                       "is_dynamic":false,
                       "value":"y-axis",
                       "area":false,
                       "datalist":[
                          
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "model_class":"ConditionalWhen",
                 "value":"BoxPlot",
                 "inputs":[
                    {
                       "model_class":"DataToolParameter",
                       "name":"InFile",
                       "argument":"--InFile",
                       "type":"data",
                       "label":"Input file",
                       "help":"Tabular data file",
                       "refresh_on_change":true,
                       "optional":false,
                       "hidden":false,
                       "is_dynamic":false,
                       "value":"None",
                       "extensions":[
                          "tabular"
                       ],
                       "edam":{
                          "edam_formats":[
                             "format_3475"
                          ],
                          "edam_data":[
                             "data_0006"
                          ]
                       },
                       "multiple":false,
                       "options":{
                          "hda":[
                             
                          ],
                          "hdca":[
                             
                          ]
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "model_class":"TextToolParameter",
                       "name":"Feature",
                       "argument":"--Features",
                       "type":"text",
                       "label":"Feature name",
                       "help":"Name of the feature (column name)",
                       "refresh_on_change":false,
                       "optional":false,
                       "hidden":false,
                       "is_dynamic":false,
                       "value":"Feature",
                       "area":false,
                       "datalist":[
                          
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "model_class":"TextToolParameter",
                       "name":"Label",
                       "argument":"--Label",
                       "type":"text",
                       "label":"Class label column",
                       "help":"Name of the column that contains class label",
                       "refresh_on_change":false,
                       "optional":false,
                       "hidden":false,
                       "is_dynamic":false,
                       "value":"class label",
                       "area":false,
                       "datalist":[
                          
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "model_class":"ConditionalWhen",
                 "value":"ScatterPlot",
                 "inputs":[
                    {
                       "model_class":"DataToolParameter",
                       "name":"InFile",
                       "argument":"--InFile",
                       "type":"data",
                       "label":"Input file",
                       "help":"Tabular data file",
                       "refresh_on_change":true,
                       "optional":false,
                       "hidden":false,
                       "is_dynamic":false,
                       "value":"None",
                       "extensions":[
                          "tabular"
                       ],
                       "edam":{
                          "edam_formats":[
                             "format_3475"
                          ],
                          "edam_data":[
                             "data_0006"
                          ]
                       },
                       "multiple":false,
                       "options":{
                          "hda":[
                             
                          ],
                          "hdca":[
                             
                          ]
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "model_class":"Conditional",
                       "name":"PlotType",
                       "type":"conditional",
                       "cases":[
                          {
                             "model_class":"ConditionalWhen",
                             "value":"2D",
                             "inputs":[
                                {
                                   "model_class":"TextToolParameter",
                                   "name":"Features1",
                                   "argument":"--RotationX",
                                   "type":"text",
                                   "label":"First feature",
                                   "help":"Feature column name",
                                   "refresh_on_change":false,
                                   "optional":false,
                                   "hidden":false,
                                   "is_dynamic":false,
                                   "value":"feature1",
                                   "area":false,
                                   "datalist":[
                                      
                                   ]
                                },
                                {
                                   "model_class":"TextToolParameter",
                                   "name":"Features2",
                                   "argument":"--RotationY",
                                   "type":"text",
                                   "label":"Second feature",
                                   "help":"Feature column name",
                                   "refresh_on_change":false,
                                   "optional":false,
                                   "hidden":false,
                                   "is_dynamic":false,
                                   "value":"feature2",
                                   "area":false,
                                   "datalist":[
                                      
                                   ]
                                }
                             ]
                          },
                          {
                             "model_class":"ConditionalWhen",
                             "value":"3D",
                             "inputs":[
                                {
                                   "model_class":"TextToolParameter",
                                   "name":"Features1",
                                   "argument":"--RotationX",
                                   "type":"text",
                                   "label":"First feature",
                                   "help":"Feature column name",
                                   "refresh_on_change":false,
                                   "optional":false,
                                   "hidden":false,
                                   "is_dynamic":false,
                                   "value":"feature1",
                                   "area":false,
                                   "datalist":[
                                      
                                   ]
                                },
                                {
                                   "model_class":"TextToolParameter",
                                   "name":"Features2",
                                   "argument":"--RotationY",
                                   "type":"text",
                                   "label":"Second feature",
                                   "help":"Feature column name",
                                   "refresh_on_change":false,
                                   "optional":false,
                                   "hidden":false,
                                   "is_dynamic":false,
                                   "value":"feature2",
                                   "area":false,
                                   "datalist":[
                                      
                                   ]
                                },
                                {
                                   "model_class":"TextToolParameter",
                                   "name":"Features3",
                                   "argument":"--FigHight",
                                   "type":"text",
                                   "label":"Third feature",
                                   "help":"Feature column name",
                                   "refresh_on_change":false,
                                   "optional":false,
                                   "hidden":false,
                                   "is_dynamic":false,
                                   "value":"feature3",
                                   "area":false,
                                   "datalist":[
                                      
                                   ]
                                }
                             ]
                          }
                       ],
                       "test_param":{
                          "model_class":"SelectToolParameter",
                          "name":"SelectPlot",
                          "argument":"",
                          "type":"select",
                          "label":"Scatter Plot type",
                          "help":"Scatter Plot type 2D or 3D.",
                          "refresh_on_change":true,
                          "optional":false,
                          "hidden":false,
                          "is_dynamic":false,
                          "value":"2D",
                          "options":[
                             [
                                "2D",
                                "2D",
                                false
                             ],
                             [
                                "3D",
                                "3D",
                                false
                             ]
                          ],
                          "display":"None",
                          "multiple":false,
                          "textable":false
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "model_class":"TextToolParameter",
                       "name":"Label",
                       "argument":"--Label",
                       "type":"text",
                       "label":"Class label column",
                       "help":"Name of the column that contains class label",
                       "refresh_on_change":false,
                       "optional":false,
                       "hidden":false,
                       "is_dynamic":false,
                       "value":"class label",
                       "area":false,
                       "datalist":[
                          
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "model_class":"ConditionalWhen",
                 "value":"WordCloud",
                 "inputs":[
                    {
                       "model_class":"DataToolParameter",
                       "name":"InFile",
                       "argument":"--InFile",
                       "type":"data",
                       "label":"Input file",
                       "help":"Fasta file with peptides",
                       "refresh_on_change":true,
                       "optional":false,
                       "hidden":false,
                       "is_dynamic":false,
                       "value":"None",
                       "extensions":[
                          "fasta"
                       ],
                       "edam":{
                          "edam_formats":[
                             "format_1929"
                          ],
                          "edam_data":[
                             "data_2044"
                          ]
                       },
                       "multiple":false,
                       "options":{
                          "hda":[
                             
                          ],
                          "hdca":[
                             
                          ]
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "model_class":"IntegerToolParameter",
                       "name":"d",
                       "argument":"--FragSize",
                       "type":"integer",
                       "label":"Size of ngrams",
                       "help":"Size of ngrams",
                       "refresh_on_change":false,
                       "min":"None",
                       "max":"None",
                       "optional":false,
                       "hidden":false,
                       "is_dynamic":false,
                       "value":"4",
                       "area":false,
                       "datalist":[
                          
                       ]
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ],
           "test_param":{
              "model_class":"SelectToolParameter",
              "name":"Plot",
              "argument":"",
              "type":"select",
              "label":"Data plotting method",
              "help":"Data plotting method",
              "refresh_on_change":true,
              "optional":false,
              "hidden":false,
              "is_dynamic":false,
              "value":"HeatMap",
              "options":[
                 [
                    "Heat Map",
                    "HeatMap",
                    false
                 ],
                 [
                    "Box Plot",
                    "BoxPlot",
                    false
                 ],
                 [
                    "Scatter Plot",
                    "ScatterPlot",
                    false
                 ],
                 [
                    "Word Cloud",
                    "WordCloud",
                    false
                 ]
              ],
              "display":"None",
              "multiple":false,
              "textable":false
           }
        }
```

I used this function to generate HTML sections dynamically

```
 AddConditoinalSection2 (input_def ) {

        input_def.id = this.uid()

        var ConditionalDiv

        for (var i in input_def.cases) {

            ConditionalDiv  = document.createElement('div')
            ConditionalDiv.className = 'ui-form-element section-row pl-2'
            ConditionalDiv.id = `${input_def.id}-section-${i}`
        
            for (var j in input_def.cases[i].inputs ) {

                if (input_def.cases[i].inputs[j].type !== 'conditional') {

                    input_def.cases[i].inputs[j].id = this.uid()
                    const SimpleRow  = document.createElement('div')
                    SimpleRow.className = 'ui-form-element section-row' 
                    SimpleRow.id = input_def.cases[i].inputs[j].id
                    ConditionalDiv.append(SimpleRow)
                } 

                else{

                    input_def.cases[i].inputs[j].id = this.uid()
                    this.AddConditoinalSection2(input_def.cases[i].inputs[j])
                }

            }

            this.element.querySelector('.Dynamic-form').append(ConditionalDiv)
   
        }

       
    }
```

and a small function to generate unique IDs.

```
   uid () {
        top.__utils__uid__ = top.__utils__uid__ || 0;
        return `uid-${top.__utils__uid__++}`;
    }
```

These functions generate sections like this

```
<form class="Dynamic-form">
    <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-0-section-0">
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-1"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-2"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-3"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-0-section-1">
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-5"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-6"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-7"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-10-section-0">
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-11"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-10-section-1">
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-13"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-14"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-15"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-0-section-2">
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-8"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-16"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-0-section-3">
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-17"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-18"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My problem is that I want to append recursive sections whenever it encounter a conditional block inside inputs `(input_def.cases[i].inputs[j].type === 'conditional')`

```
  <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-0-section-1">
    <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-5"></div>
    <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-6"></div>
    <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-7"></div>

    <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-10-section-0">
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-11"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-10-section-1">
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-13"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-14"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-15"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

what changes should I make in this code to get this result?

Final result that I want

```
<form class="Dynamic-form">
    <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-0-section-0">
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-1"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-2"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-3"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-4"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-0-section-1">
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-5"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-6"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-7"></div>

        <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-10-section-0">
            <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-11"></div>
            <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-12"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-10-section-1">
            <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-13"></div>
            <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-14"></div>
            <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-15"></div>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-0-section-2">
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-8"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-16"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-form-element section-row pl-2" id="uid-0-section-3">
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-17"></div>
        <div class="ui-form-element section-row" id="uid-18"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a small change in your function to make this work. You need to add an argument to the AddConditoinalSection2 function to specify in which parent to want to append the div.

```
AddConditoinalSection2 (input_def,parent ) {

    input_def.id = this.uid()

    var ConditionalDiv

    for (var i in input_def.cases) {

        ConditionalDiv  = document.createElement('div')
        ConditionalDiv.className = 'ui-form-element section-row pl-2'
        ConditionalDiv.id = `${input_def.id}-section-${i}`
    
        for (var j in input_def.cases[i].inputs ) {

            if (input_def.cases[i].inputs[j].type !== 'conditional') {

                input_def.cases[i].inputs[j].id = this.uid()
                const SimpleRow  = document.createElement('div')
                SimpleRow.className = 'ui-form-element section-row' 
                SimpleRow.id = input_def.cases[i].inputs[j].id
                ConditionalDiv.append(SimpleRow)
            } 

            else{

                input_def.cases[i].inputs[j].id = this.uid()
                this.AddConditoinalSection2(input_def.cases[i].inputs[j],ConditionalDiv)
            }

        }

        parent.querySelector('.Dynamic-form').append(ConditionalDiv)

    }
```

and when calling the function initially just pass the main div a parent

```
AddConditoinalSection2 (data,this.element.querySelector('.Dynamic-form'))
```